# Cardinality violation: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Am getting an error that the columns are not matching but i checked and they are. Here is the SQL script:

```
SELECT student_no
     , firstname
     , lastname
     , middlename
     , sub_classes.name as sub_class_name 
  FROM 
     (SELECT payments.students_student_no as student_no
           , SUM(payments.amount) as amount 
        FROM students 
        JOIN payments                
          ON payments.students_student_no = students.student_no
        JOIN sub_classes 
          ON students.sub_classes_id = sub_classes.id
       WHERE payment_type_id = ? 
         AND academic_year = ? 
         AND term = ? 
       GROUP 
          BY student_no
       UNION ALL
      SELECT student_no
           , firstname
           , lastname
           , middlename
           , sub_classes.name as sub_class_name 
        FROM students 
        JOIN sub_classes 
          ON students.sub_classes_id = sub_classes.id
       GROUP 
          BY student_no
     ) results 
 GROUP 
    BY student_no
```

Comment: [Edit] your post to quote the full error and to show `create table` scripts/schemas for both tables.

Comment: `but i checked and they are` I checked. They're not.

Answer (score 1):

In the second select for UNION ALL you have wro9ng number of columns repect the first. In the code below  have   changed the  (firstname, lastname, middlename, sub_classes.name ) with null

```
SELECT student_no, firstname, lastname, middlename, sub_classes.name as sub_class_name 
FROM (
    SELECT payments.students_student_no as student_no, SUM(payments.amount) as amount 
    FROM students INNER JOIN payments ON payments.students_student_no=students.student_no  
    INNER JOIN sub_classes ON(students.sub_classes_id=sub_classes.id) WHERE payment_type_id=? AND academic_year=? AND term=? GROUP BY student_no
    UNION ALL
    SELECT student_no,null 
    FROM students 
    INNER JOIN sub_classes ON students.sub_classes_id=sub_classes.id
) results
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the number of columns in 2 select statements. Please see below.

```
SELECT payments.students_student_no as student_no, SUM(payments.amount) as amount   --> number of columns should be same as the below select statement. Also the datatype of each column
FROM students
...
...
GROUP BY student_no
UNION ALL
SELECT student_no, firstname, lastname, middlename, sub_classes.name as sub_class_name   --> Number of columns here should be same as the upper select statement. Also the datatype of each column
FROM students
...
GROUP BY student_no
```